# Run Love2D on iphone and android

Tags: android, ios, lua, love2d

I have a game developed in lua using love 2d, and now i want to run it in ios/android.

Is there any porting or way available to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are experimental/inprogress ports to both platforms.

[Andriod](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=76979&sid=30c1f766e912532cb374e300a16c423b) This one is not associated with the Love2D team.

[iOS](http://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=76985) This one is being created by the Love2D team.